# How can I make CGI::Application::Dispatch work with mod_perl?

Tags: mod-perl

Ok, so I am trying to set up a Dispatcher with mod_perl and I don't really know what I am doing wrong.  I am fairly positive that the issue is with my mod_perl configuration.  Here is what I think is relevant:

**Apache Directory Config**

```
<Directory  "C:/Documents and Settings/frew/My Documents/acd">
   SetHandler perl-script
   PerlHandler ACD::Dispatch
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex Default.html
</Directory>
```

**Note**: ACD::Dispatch is in acd/ACD.

**ACD::Dispatch**

```
package ACD::Dispatch;
use base 'CGI::Application::Dispatch';
sub dispatch_args {
    return {
        prefix  => 'ACD',
        table   => [
        ''                => { app => 'Controller', rm => 'awesome' },
        ':app/:rm'        => { },
        ],
    };
}
```

And probably most importantly, the **Apache errors:**

```
[Mon Jan 12 17:42:08 2009] [error] [client 10.6.1.73] failed to resolve handler `ACD::Dispatch': Can't locate ACD/Dispatch.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/usr/site/lib C:/usr/lib . C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2) at (eval 3) line 3.\n
```

Thanks for any help!

**Update**:  I needed to add this to my Apache config:

```
<Perl>
   use lib '/path/to/acd';
</Perl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, based on the error message:

> ACD::Dispatch: Can't locate
>   ACD/Dispatch.pm in @INC (@INC
>   contains: C:/usr/site/lib C:/usr/lib .
>   C:/Program Files/Apache Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2

and the fact that you said:

> ACD::Dispatch is in acd/ACD.

It looks like you need to put the "acd" directory in the @INC path, using its absolute pathname.

Although you might think '.' is on @INC and that should be your `acd` directory, I don't that that it is, under mod_perl.  See, for example, [this discussion](http://www.justskins.com/forums/mod_perl-use-lib-and-stuff-84152.html).